# Let $H$ be a fixed graph on $n$ vertices. The number of labeled copies of $H$ in $K_n$ is $\frac{n!}{|\text{Aut}(H)|}$.

Tags: combinatorics, graph-theory, solution-verification

> Let $H$ be a fixed graph on $n$ vertices. The number of labeled copies of $H$ in $K_n$ is $\frac{n!}{|\text{Aut}(H)|}$, where $\text{Aut}(H)$ is the set of automorphisms of $H$.

This is a remark from some note that I’m reading. I’m trying to understand why this is true.

To demonstrate, let $H$ be the graph on $5$ vertices below. My thinking is that, a mapping $V(H) \to V(K_5)$ would give a copy of $H$ in $K_n$, and $|\text{Aut}(H)|$ should account for some sort of multiple counting. This is what got me confused.

[image]

For an example, let one mapping be
$$a \mapsto v_1, b \mapsto v_2, c \mapsto v_3, d \mapsto v_4, e \mapsto v_5,$$
and another mapping be
$$a \mapsto v_1, b \mapsto v_4, c \mapsto v_3, d \mapsto v_2, e \mapsto v_5.$$
How are these two mappings the same?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It may not be the case that the mappings are the same, but both mappings define the same subgraph of $K_5$ which is isomorphic to $H$, which you can see if you draw the images of both edges under the mapping.

The idea of the proof of the $n!/|\operatorname{Aut}H|$ formula is as follows. There are $n!$ ways to bijectively map the vertices of $H$ to that of $K_n$. Each of these bijections $f:V(H)\to V(K_n)$ defines a subgraph of $K_n$, where for each $v,w\in H$, $f(v)$ is joined to $f(w)$ in the subgraph if and only if $v$ is joined to $w$ in $H$. However, some of these subgraphs are the same, meaning they have the same set of edges. Namely, for any automorphism $\varphi\in \operatorname{Aut}H$, the map $f\circ \phi$ defines a differing mapping $V(H)\to V(K_n)$, but the resulting subgraph is the same, since $\phi(v)\sim \phi(w)\iff v\sim w$. This overcounting is corrected by dividing by $|\operatorname{Aut} H|$.